# Button width is not stretch

Tags: wpf, mahapps.metro

I try to use the metro style from MahApps but buttons becomes not "SizeToContent" or becomes not AutoResized or something like that.

This is my button style

```
<Style x:Key="GrayMetroButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource LightMetroWindowButtonStyle}">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
        </Style>
```

This is the style using in WPF. The width of the button's column is larger than the button needed to check autoresize.

```
<Grid Grid.Row="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding ManifestFileName}" Margin="5" />
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Change" Margin="2" Visibility="{Binding LoadButtonVisibility}" Command="{Binding LoadManifest}" Style="{StaticResource GrayMetroButtonStyle}" />
            </Grid>
```

And result is
[image]

As you see, content is out of the buttons width range. 
If i clear the style refference, button get a properly behavior.
[image]

Which property are rule this behavior? How can i make this buttons autoresizable?

Thanks for replies.

Comment: can you try modifying margin and padding in your style??

Comment: Please check "LightMetroWindowButtonStyle" style. If you will remove it from your style then it will work. That means some thing is strange in that style.

Comment: Indeed, as the name "Light**MetroWindow**ButtonStyle" indicates, this style is intended for the control buttons in the Metro Window title bar.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the comments in the MahApps sources, `LightMetroWindowButtonStyle` is intended for the minimize, maximize, and close buttons in the title bar of a Metro-style window.  For that reason, the style sets a fixed `Width` of `34`.

It looks like the 'standard' button style for MahApps is `MahApps.Metro.Styles.MetroButton`, so I would suggest using that instead.  It actually looks like this is the style that gets applied *by default*, as the second image you posted (the button with the style cleared) looks like it has this style already applied.

There are others too, like  `SquareButtonStyle` and `AccentedSquareButtonStyle`, which are showcased in the MahApps example app:

[image: MahApps Metro Demo Application]

If you want the 'flat' look, `MetroFlatButton` looks pretty similar to the button in the first image.  You can see the various MahApps button styles [in the MahApps docs](http://mahapps.com/controls/buttons.html) and see the actual source code [on GitHub](http://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/89b57f7aaf9c4027c730fd9df90bbcf52f0d9629/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.Buttons.xaml) .

Note that some of the button styles force their content to display in lowercase.  If you want to avoid this, you can extend one of the MahApps styles and override a single property, e.g.:

```
<Style x:Key="SquareButtonStyleNormalCase"
       BasedOn="{StaticResource SquareButtonStyle}"
       TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="m:ControlsHelper.ContentCharacterCasing"
          Value="Normal" />
</Style>
```